# Difference Map<A,B> foo = new HashMap<A,B>() and new HashMap<>()?

Tags: java, generics

When we create object, I have no idea whether I have to insert generic type or not.

```
 1. Map<A,B> foo = new HashMap<A,B>()  
 2. Map<A,B> foo = new HashMap<>()
```

Is there anyone who can tell difference?

Comment: There is no difference. The compiler infers the generic types automatically, when they are given on the left hand side.

Answer (score 2):

The diamond operator (`<>`) was introduced in Java 7 and saves you some typing. There is no difference.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the two. The second was introduced in Java 7 -- the `<>` is called the diamond operator and is a shorthand for the first.

Answer (score 2):

Java has always been criticized for being too verbose, which is one of the reasons for introducing the diamond (`<>`) in Java7.

The compiler *infers* the type-parameter by inspecting the type-parameter(s) from the left-hand side of the expression and you're not required to explicitly provide type-parameters for the right-hand side.

There's no real difference between explicitly providing the type-parameters, and relying on the type inference feature.